# How to connect to Oracle DB using protractor+Jasmine?

Tags: protractor

My tests needs to connect to Oracle DB and fetch some data and perform UI Validations.I have gone through node.js node-oracledb package ,but it has pre-requisites of python,visual studio etc.Any other package that could be used with simpler installations?

Comment: Hi found the solution for this .we could use REST APIs instead of connecting to the database directly.

Comment: The community maintains some pre-built node-oracledb binaries at https://www.npmjs.com/package/oracledb-pb which might meet your quality & security requirements